# GNUplot: ';' expected gif terminal

Tags: animation, plot, error-handling, gnuplot, gif

I am trying to generate an animation following the time evolution of two different plots, using GNUplot (version 4.6). The first issue I ran into was that an individual plot would be animated just fine, but when I tried to do the entire sequence, it would only plot one time frame. 
The current issue I am running into is a ';' expected error. I am kind of new to gnuplot, and am not sure what a semicolon does, or where it might be necessary. 
This is my entire script:

```
set term gif small animate 
set output "./output/test.gif"
#set title "Abundance"

do for [ii=700:ii=900] {
   set multiplot
   set xrange [80:120]          #alt [0:180]
   set yrange [61:65]           #alt [0:110]

   set xtics 10
   set ytics 1
   set grid ytics lc rgb "#bbbbbb" lw 1 lt 1
   set grid xtics lc rgb "#bbbbbb" lw 1 lt 1
   set size ratio -1
   set style fill transparent solid 0.5
   set cbrange [1e-15:1e-03]
   set logscale cb
   set colorbox horizontal user origin 0.1, 0.15 size 0.8, 0.04
   set format cb "10e%L"
   unset key

   set palette rgb 33,13,10     # DEFAULT- this is the original one
   set origin 0,0
   set xlabel "N"
   set ylabel "Z"
   set cblabel "Abundance"
   plot './output/texts/abun_'.ii.'.txt' using 2:1:(0.5):(.5):3 w boxxyerrorbars lc palette title "Abundance"

   unset grid xtics
   unset grid ytics
   unset style fill 
   unset colorbox 
   set origin 0,0.35
   set yrange[61:65]
   set xrange [80:120]
   plot './output/texts/abun_'.ii.'.txt' using 2:1
   unset multiplot
}
```

The terminal says the error is on line 39, which is the last line. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: at least Gnuplot `5.2` does not support `unset grid xtics` - it should be split into two commands `unset grid; unset xtics;`...

Comment: @ewcz Wow, that did the trick! Thanks!